# What is the complement of a loop?

Tags: algebraic-topology

My Algebraic Topology book says

> $A$ is a loop in the complement of another loop $B$

What does "in the complement of" mean here?

Comment: That depends on the context I guess. Can you show us the reference?

Comment: Hatcher, pg. 23 "let us regard one of the circles, say $C$, in the complement of the other two, $A$ and $B$..."

Comment: At p.22, it says "Consider two linked circles $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^3...$". I believe he continues to assume that everything is taking place in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in the following, so taking a complement would also be with respect to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch- So here the complement simply means $\Bbb{R^2}\setminus \text{loop}$?

Comment: @algebraically_speaking $\Bbb R^3 \setminus \text{loop}$

Answer (score 4):

In topology, the complement of a loop (or a knot, or a link...) is just the set-theoretic complement: $X \setminus A$  where $A$ is the loop and $X$ is the ambient space. The ambient space is meant to be inferred from the context; usually it's either $S^3$ or $\mathbb R^3$.